# Semiprimes with three (and more) numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization, semiprimes

Semiprimes (pq-numbers) guarantee that if p and q are prime numbers the only divisors of the result of `p*q` are p and q.

My question is: Does this hold true for `p*q*r` as well?

For example `3*5*7=105`. Are there any three numbers other than 3, 5 and 7 so that `x*y*z=105`?

Of course if there are non, the follow up question is, what about the other prime-multiplications like `p*q*r*s`?

I have this question because I came across [an article](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/06/28/magazine/greetings-et-please-dont-murder-us.html?_r=0) about sending messages to space and the [Arecibo message](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arecibo_message) used a semiprime to transmit information about the layout of the message. If we could do the same with three numbers we could make a 3d layout.

> The cardinality of 1,679 was chosen because it is a semiprime (the
>   product of two prime numbers), to be arranged rectangularly as 73 rows
>   by 23 columns. The alternative arrangement, 23 rows by 73 columns,
>   produces jumbled nonsense (as do all other X/Y formats). The message
>   forms the image shown on the right, or its inverse, when translated
>   into graphics, characters and spaces.[5]
>
> from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arecibo_message)

Comment: I am not sure whether I have understood the intent of the question, but it seems that you want to know whether a number which is a product of $n$ distinct primes can essentially only be written as a product of $n$ factors in one way. If so, the answer is yes, if we do not allow $1$ as a factor.

Comment: A 3D layout is much more complex because $3\times 5\times 7 =5\times 3 \times 7= 7\times 3 \times 5\ldots$ there are 6 possibilities, not only 2 like in 2D and the aliens would find hard time reconstructing the message

Comment: @Raffaele I didn't even think about that as I wrote my answer. I think you should add an answer, expanding on your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $p$ and $q$ are distinct prime numbers, then $pq$ actually has four divisors in $\mathbb Z^+$: $1, p, q, pq$. What you want to know about are what we might call "nontrivial" divisors, divisors other than 1 and the number itself. In which case $pq$ does indeed have two nontrivial divisors: $p$ and $q$.

If $p$, $q$ and $r$ are distinct prime numbers, then $pqr$ does indeed have $p$, $q$ and $r$ among its nontrivial divisors. But it also has $pq$, $pr$ and $qr$ among its nontrivial divisors.

To use your example of 105: its nontrivial divisors are 3, 5, 7, 15, 21, 35. So if we sent the aliens a 3 by 5 by 7 cuboid array, they might misunderstand it as a 3 by 35 rectangular array, or a 5 by 21, or 7 by 15.

Even with a $p$ by $q$ array, there is the danger they might misunderstand it. With more possible ways to interpret the message, the potential for misunderstanding increases, along with the potential for star wars.